# Как обратится к родительскому элементу в js?

Tags: javascript

Нужно обратится к родительскому элементу на чистом js. Например, у меня есть  кнопка в строке таблицы , при нажатии на которую должен удалится полностью весь ряд таблицы. Как это сделать?

Comment: el.parentElement

Answer (score 2):

Достаем родителя элемента в JavaScript

```
function getParent(el){ 
    if (el.parentElement){
        return el.parentElement;
  }

  if (el.parentNode){
        return el.parentNode;
  }

  return null;
}
```